# ImportError: No module named rest_framework on running collectstatic

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, pip

I found many questions with the same error, but none were addressing the actual cause of my problem so I am posting this. I am facing the issue in my (digital ocean) Linux production server.

I have python 3.5.2 in virtualenv, and python2.7.12 in the machine. 
I have installed djangorestframework in virtualenv using command `pip install djangorestframework`
But did not install it in the actual machine (on 2.7)

python3 in the venv is working and importing rest_framework fine:

```
(venv) myname@server:/www/site$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rest_framework
>>> exit()
```

python2 in the machine is working and not importing rest_framework because its not installed.

```
myname@server:/www/site$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rest_framework
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named rest_framework
>>> exit()
```

On running collectstatic command inside virtualenv I am getting the following error. It seems to be looking for the package in python2.7 and not inside virtualenv.

```
(venv) myname@server:/www/site$ sudo python manage.py collectstatic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named rest_framework
```

My questing is that, Is it necessary for the package to be present in the server machine outside venv also? 
If so, why? and Should I install rest_framework in the server on py2.7? If I do so, could it possibly break something?

Comment: is there `DEBUG=True` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: yes, it is set to true.

Comment: You might possibly be running outside of venv mistakely???

Comment: I activated venv before runnig collectstatic command. Its shows activated here-  `(venv) myname@server:/www/site$ sudo python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: its beacuse you have created venv with python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (venv) myname@server:/www/site$ sudo python manage.py collectstatic

The issue is with the use of `sudo` here. It discards the environment to use the target account's one therefore discarding your virtual env.
If you want to keep it, you should likely use the `-E` flag to preserve the environment:

```
(venv) myname@server:/www/site$ sudo -E python manage.py collectstatic
```

you could also call the virtual env's python directly as well which would free you from setting up the visual env beforehand:

```
 (venv) myname@server:/www/site$ which python
 <path-to-python>
 (venv) myname@server:/www/site$ sudo <path-to-python> manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the second solution and it solved the issue.